# Are you allowed to forcefully remove someone from your property if they don't leave after being told to in Germany?

Tags: germany, trespass

Is it legal to forcefully push or drag someone out of your property if they refuse to leave after being told to? I am talking strictly about Germany's laws.

Comment: FWIW, I think that this duplicate question was intended to be a rewording of the linked original question that conformed to the Law.SE policy of not asking for specific legal advice in the reasonable expectation that the other question would be closed. It should have been an edit to the previous question but perhaps the poster didn't know how to do that.